# Automate paths that I insert after command in python

Tags: python, terminal, moviepy

I want to make a simple gif to mp4 converter with `moviepy` module. problem is that every time I have to convert a different file, I have to open `convert.py` file and edit path in

`clip = mp.VideoFileClip(path/to/.gif)`

I want to make something similar to this:

`./convert.py /home/user/Desktop/file.gif`

So that I can specify paths directly via terminal without changing python executable, any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here are terminal output and my script

**terminal:**
`./convert.py /home/xinto/Desktop/vanced_9_1.gif`

```py
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./convert.py", line 10, in <module>
    clip = mp.VideoFileClip('fn')
  File "/home/xinto/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 91, in __init__
    fps_source=fps_source)
  File "/home/xinto/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 33, in __init__
    fps_source)
  File "/home/xinto/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 276, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    "path.")%filename)
OSError: MoviePy error: the file fn could not be found!
Please check that you entered the correct path
```

**Here is my script:**
`#!/usr/bin/python3.7`

```py
import moviepy.editor as mp
import os.path
import os
import sys

fn = sys.argv

clip = mp.VideoFileClip('fn')
clip.write_videofile("export.mp4")
```

Comment: `fn = sys.argv` wouldencapsulate ALL *sys.argv*, including `sys.argv[0]` which is the name of the script itself. `sys.argv[1]` would be the first passed argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and thanks for your first post to the community. I would like to start by letting you know I am not a *Python* programmer but if I understand the question correctly, you are most likely not one either.

Which is fine.

A little ***google-foo*** brought me there:

[How to use *sys.argv* in *Python*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv)

This web ressources treats of python sys.argv to achieve just what i think you are asking. I certainly believe that this solves your problem fairly quickly and easily.

Whish you the best and let us know how you manage. Also, remember that a quick search on the internet will help you learn and progress, assuming you understand the given information

Thanks

Edit:

The following bit of code would display arguments passed to the program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for x in sys.argv:
        print ("Argument: ", x);
```

The following code would make sure there is at least one parameter being passed to the program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

if len (sys.argv) != 2 :
        print ("Usage: ", str(sys.argv[0]));
        sys.exit (1)

print ("Passed argument: ", str(sys.argv[1]));
```

This code would ultimately set variable 'clip' and print it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

if len (sys.argv) != 2 :
        print ("Usage: ", str(sys.argv[0]), "[FILEPATH]");
        sys.exit (1)

clip = str(sys.argv[1]) + '.gif';

print ("Clip is: ", clip);
```

Of course, you should implement file verification to check if file exist...

Once you understand the basic of sys.argv, you can check other ressource like [More fun with *sys.argv*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/argv/more-fun-with-sys-argv)

--- More edits ---

After lookig at your last comment, saying the module doesn't allow for variables... i couldn't help but code something to verify as this is not normal. This is what i came up with and please remember i am not *Python* programmer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import moviepy.editor as mp
import sys

if len (sys.argv) != 3 :
        print ("Usage:", str(sys.argv[0]), "[GIF FILEPATH] [OUTPUT MP4]");
        sys.exit (1)

gifFILE = str(sys.argv[1]);
outMP4 = str(sys.argv[2]);

print ("GIF filepath:", gifFILE);
print ("MP4 output:", outMP4);

clip = mp.VideoFileClip(gifFILE);
clip.write_videofile(outMP4);
```

Which resulted in a perfect output mp4 file from a 2mb original gif input.

Extra:

If you only wanted to create a mp4 from a gif file, a simple *FFMpeg* command would do the trick.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.gif -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" OUTPUT.mp4
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, you made things easier, however that created a new problem, I will update OP and will post terminal output too. Thanks!

Comment: It's okay if you update your original post as long as you take into consideration of NOT making my answer irrelevant. And please, upvote if you think it's worth it.

Comment: You really helped me so i have no rights to mark your answer as irrelevant ;)

Comment: Updated code to more suit your issue. With all the respect in the world... you have a long ways ahead and the learning curve is steep! Enjoy

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me, unfortunately module itself does not support variables other than direct paths. it's kinda shame. but still, thank you very much!

Comment: Haha, you are more of a python programmer than I am. Thanks for helping me and I'm sorry for wasting your time!